# How to convert a 3D point cloud to a depth image?

Tags: c++, image, mapping, cloud, point

For my work I have to convert a point cloud to a grey scale (depth) image meaning that the z coordinate of each XYZ point in the cloud represents a shade of grey. For mapping a Z coordinate from the [z_min, z_max] interval to the [0..255] interval I used the map function of Arduino:

`float map(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max)
 { return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min; }`

With that done I need to write the result to an image, the problem being that the clouds that I have can have millions of points so I can't just write them 1 by 1 to an image in order. Let's say that I have 3000x1000 ordered XY points. How would I do if I wanted to write them to a 700x300 pixels image? I hope the question is clear, thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Maybe just scale the coordinates and add up the greyscale values if multiple points lie on one pixel?

Comment: Hi, I had that in mind as well but let's consider this. One cloud row is equal to 3600 points and one image row is equal to 1680 pixels. The result would be 2.41 points per pixel. Do I just go with 2 points per pixel and fill the non-occupied pixels with 0s?

Comment: It is not clear whether your point cloud is dense. That said, when multiple points land in the same pixel, I would take the z-value of the closest one, as would happen if you rasterized them. So if you don't want to do this task by hand, just submit your points to say OpenGL and let it rasterize them for you, then read out the depth buffer.

Comment: Apparently, when there are more points landing on the same pixels, I add only the one having the biggest z value (aka biggest grey scale value). I will work on it today, if I manage to do it I'll post the method as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my problem. It is a fairy long algorithm for stack overflow but bear with me. The idea is write a vector of XY grey scale points as a [pgm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) file.

**Step 1:** `cloud_to_greyscale` - function that converts an **XYZ Point Cloud** into a **vector of XY grey scale points** and that receives a `cloud` as a parameter:

```
 for each point pt in cloud
     point_xy_greyscale.x <- pt.x
     point_xy_greyscale.y <- pt.y
     point_xy_greyscale.greyscale <- map(pt.z, z_min, z_max, 0, 255)
     greyscale_vector.add(point_xy_greyscale)
 loop

 return greyscale_vector
```

**Step 2:** `greyscale_to_image` - function that writes the previously returned vector as a `greyscale_image`, a class that has a `width`, a `height` and a `_pixels` member corresponding to a double dimensional array of `unsigned short` usually. The function receives the following parameters: a `greyscale_vector` (to be turned into the image) and an `x_epsilon` that will help us delimit the `x` pixel coordinates for our points, knowing that the `x` point coordinates are floats (and thus not suitable as array indices).

*A little background info: I work on something called **widop** clouds so in my 3D space `x` is the `width`, `y` is the `depth` and `z` is the `height`. Also worth noting is the fact that `y` is an `integer` so for my problem, the `height` of the image is easy to find: it's `y_max - y_min`. To find the `width` of the image, follow the algorithm below and if it isn't clear I will answer any questions and I'm open to suggestions.*

```
img_width <- 0;    // image width
img_height <- y_max - y_min + 1    // image height

// determining image width
for each point greyscale_xy_point in greyscale_vector
    point_x_cell <- (pt.x - x_min) * x_epsilon * 10

    if point_x_cell > img_width
        img_width <- point_x_cell + 1
loop

// defining and initializing image with the calculated height and width
greyscale_img(img_width, img_height)

// initializing greyscale image points
for y <- 0 to greyscale_img.height
    for x <- 0 to greyscale_img.width
        greyscale_img[y][x] = 0
    loop
loop

// filling image with vector data
for each point point_xy_greyscale in greyscale_vector
    image_x = (point_xy_greyscale.x - x_min) * x_epsilon * 10
    image_y = point_xy_greyscale.y - y_min

    greyscale_image[image_y][image_x] = point_xy_greyscale.greyscale
loop

return greyscale_image
```

The only thing left to do is to write the image to the file, but that is easy to do, you can just find the format rules in the previous link related to the pgm format. I hope this helps someone.

**EDIT_1:** I added a picture of the result. It is supposed to be a railway and the reason it's fairly dark is that there are some objects that are tall so ground objects are darker.

[depth image of railway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od6sa.png)

Comment: what is your map function in your answer?

Comment: In your 3D space, x is the width, y is the depth and z is the height. Hence, how is it possible to the height of the image to be equal to y_max - y_min? Maybe some misunderstanding of my part, but could you please clarify this? TKs